# Losing data when using more than one output in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash

We currently have a logstash with the following configuration:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    id => "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    host => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    exchange => "xxxxxx_xxxxxxx_xxxxx"
    key => "xxxxxx_xxxxxxx_xxxxx"
    queue => "xxxxxx_xxxxxxx_xxxxx"
    user => "shipper"
    password => "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    durable => true
    type => "xxxxxx_xxxxxxx_xxxxx"
    threads => 1
    prefetch_count => 100
    connection_timeout => 10000
    vhost => "vhost_xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200"]
    index => "xxxxxx_xxxxxxx_xxxxx"
    document_type => "xxxxxx_xxxxxxx_xxxxx"
    timeout => 30000
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["load_balanced_host:80"]
    index => "xxxxxx_xxxxxxx_xxxxx"
    document_type => "xxxxxx_xxxxxxx_xxxxx"
    timeout => 30000
  }
}
```

The first output (the one with 3 ip's) is the new cluster (where we want to migrate to). The second one, is a load balanced cluster provided by amazon elasticsearch service.
They have the same mappings.
They're both in the same version (2.3).

The problem is: the new cluster loses messages (or they don't get delivered, idk).
Let's take this scenario for instance:

```
    1 - MSG_A, MSG_B and MSG_C arrives in the rabbitMq;
    2 - Logstash processes MSG_A, MSG_B and MSG_C;
    3 - Logstash logs shows nothing anormal;
    4 - Checking the old elasticsearch cluster all the messages are there (MSG_A, MSG_B and MSG_C);
    5 - Checking the new elasticsearch cluster there's messages missing.
```

Anyone has any idea where I can start the investigation or why this happens?

Thanks!

Tried to switch output order (new cluster first/old cluster after and old cluster first/new cluster after) and nothing changed - still losing messages in the new cluster.

Comment: did you check your logstash and new cluster logs? The main reason why I'd expect event loss is if it's receiving a message that does not match the current index mapping.

Comment: Yes, I've checked the mappings and analyzer and they're the same. The only thing I've noticed is a minor version difference (2.3.2 Aws / 2.3.5 Custom one).